# Updating alpha value in css custom property doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I am trying to override the alpha value in HSLA using CSS custom property.
In the code below, I wanted to update the alpha value to 0.1, so the final output should be `hsla(0, 0%, 26%, 0.1)`. When I inspect the element, it has what I expected, but the rendered output doesn't have the alpha value applied. Any solution for this?

Thanks!

```css
:root {
  --bg-color: hsla(0, 0%, 26%, var(--a, 1));
}

.dark {
  color: #efefef;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

.light {
  --a: 0.1;
  color: #888;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="dark">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident quia, at aliquid temporibus optio ipsa ullam eaque et fugiat? Aliquid fugit facere officiis nostrum. Consequatur maiores aspernatur ipsum ratione facilis!</div>
<div style="margin-top: 3rem"></div>
<div class="light">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident quia, at aliquid temporibus optio ipsa ullam eaque et fugiat? Aliquid fugit facere officiis nostrum. Consequatur maiores aspernatur ipsum ratione facilis!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:

```css
:root {
  --a: 1;
  --hsl: 0, 0%, 26%;
}

.dark {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: hsl(var(--hsl), var(--a));
}

.light {
  --a: 0.1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: hsl(var(--hsl), var(--a));
}
```

```html
<div class="dark">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident quia, at aliquid temporibus optio ipsa ullam eaque et fugiat? Aliquid fugit facere officiis nostrum. Consequatur maiores aspernatur ipsum ratione facilis!</div>
<div style="margin-top: 3rem"></div>
<div class="light">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident quia, at aliquid temporibus optio ipsa ullam eaque et fugiat? Aliquid fugit facere officiis nostrum. Consequatur maiores aspernatur ipsum ratione facilis!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a scope issue. `--bg-color` is already defined in `:root` and has a higher order of importance then when it's used in a class. So `--bg-color` would need to be redefined to get the change applied.

---

Or reverse the order of importance, such that declaring `--a` at a higher specificity (like a class), means it's already defined before it's used in the variable declaration of `--bg-color`.

Imagine you are the css processor,
You look at `:root` first, see definition for `--bg-color` and you remember it.
Now when you process the rest of the css rules you know, you need to use it. It won't go back and redefine a variable that it has already processed.

```css
div {
  --bg-color: hsla(0, 0%, 26%, var(--a, 1));
}

.dark {
  color: #efefef;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

.light {
  --a: 0.1;
  color: #888;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

Comment: Does a property defined in `root` have higher importance than the same property defined in a specific block? I thought `.light { --a: 0.1; }` is more specific than `:root { --a: 1; }`, so by the specificity rule, shouldn't browser use 0.1 opacity instead of 1? Also I don't understand why browser inspector shows `hsla(0, 0%, 26%, 0.1)` value but renders `hsla(0, 0%, 26%, 1)` output.

Comment: Yeah that's correct. `--a` in `.light` would have a higher specificity. But you're not using `--a` there. You are using `--bg-color` right. Which has already been processed and defined as a variable.